# What is the nested tables limit for major browsers?

Tags: html

Backstory: When working with Microsoft Dynamics CRM, I discovered a document from Microsoft stating that every browser has a specific limit of how many nested tables you can have.

> There is a limit to the number of nested steps you can use in a dialog. The limit depends on the browser you’re using and isn’t a limit in Microsoft Dynamics CRM. The nested steps are rendered in the browser as nested tables. **Some browsers support more levels of nested tables than others.**

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509010(v=crm.6).aspx#limitations)

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770573/what-is-the-maximum-depth-of-html-documents-in-practice) but it is more generalised into ANY element, rather than a table in a table, which is what I am seeing.

What are the real-world limitations for major browsers?

From my real-life example, I am looking at approximately 61 nested tables. Although, I am unsure, as copying the entire page source reveals 6 opening `<table>` tags and 61 `</table>` tags

Comment: Interesting question

Comment: I understand the theoretical curiosity of this limit.  I'm just having a hard time understanding the practical applications of 53 nested tables in your real-life example.  Certainly there is another more practical design to portraying the data?

Comment: SharePoint makes way more nested tables than this for a single div element on your page so I'd say 61 is no problem.

Comment: @jusopi Yes, there definitely is! My practical discovery of there being such limits is while I am using Microsoft Dynamics CRM. The workflow builder creates each nested step as a new table inside the previous steps table.

I digress, though. I think it more useful to understand the real-world limitations, rather than for one specific & outdated piece of software.

Comment: That's baffling but I'll accept it.  I guess from a purely UI standpoint, I can't imagine how these tables would be readable in a standard browser window.  It would have to span several horizontal pages no?

Comment: FWIW Firefox does only support 33 nested tables (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=452038)

Comment: Bookmarked...invaluable info should I ever find myself in a situation where I'm in need of nesting an inordinate amount of data that needs to be recursively self-referenced...er...33 times?

Comment: @zer00ne today I received email with some list. 2 items of 17 was not rendered. I opened it in Chrome and found that items are nested tables. I think they was inaccurately copied from Word. Anyway Chrome renders them all but Firefox doesn't

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As noted by [@Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39969762/what-is-the-nested-tables-limit-for-major-browsers#comment67219706_39969762), Firefox is currently limited to 33 nested tables. Cross-browser, this represents the current practical nested table limit. Your 61 nested tables will not currently render in Firefox.

---

Let's go further and make a real-life test. We can open a new nested table on each line and let the browser fill in the closing tags:

```
<table><tr><td>1
<table><tr><td>2
<table><tr><td>3
<table><tr><td>4
<table><tr><td>5
<!-- ad infinitum -->
```

### Results

I tested Internet Explorer 11, Firefox (Windows + Android) and Chrome (Windows + Android) — Edge and Safari would be useful to test as well.

#### Most nested tables rendered

**Internet Explorer 11** managed to render 262 nested tables correctly. Any more would be rendered briefly before crashing the browser.

#### Runner up

**Google Chrome** (Version 53.0.2785.143 m (64-bit)) manages to render 378 nested tables, but only the **first 127** are rendered correctly, with the rest breaking out of the outermost table. Any further nested tables caused the tab to crash. This behaviour is the same on mobile.

#### Least

**Firefox** (Version 49.01) only managed to render 33 nested tables correctly. The following nested tables were simply not rendered and the browser did not crash even when 1000 nested tables were given to it. This behaviour is the same on mobile.

#### Try it yourself

Here are 1000 nested tables. **Note:** Testing all 1000 tables will probably cause your browser to crash.

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
 <table><tr><td>1
 <table><tr><td>2
 <table><tr><td>3
 <table><tr><td>4
 <table><tr><td>5
 <table><tr><td>6
 <table><tr><td>7
 <table><tr><td>8
 <table><tr><td>9
 <table><tr><td>10
 <table><tr><td>11
 <table><tr><td>12
 <table><tr><td>13
 <table><tr><td>14
 <table><tr><td>15
 <table><tr><td>16
 <table><tr><td>17
 <table><tr><td>18
 <table><tr><td>19
 <table><tr><td>20
 <table><tr><td>21
 <table><tr><td>22
 <table><tr><td>23
 <table><tr><td>24
 <table><tr><td>25
 <table><tr><td>26
 <table><tr><td>27
 <table><tr><td>28
 <table><tr><td>29
 <table><tr><td>30
 <table><tr><td>31
 <table><tr><td>32
 <table><tr><td>33
 <table><tr><td>34
 <table><tr><td>35
 <table><tr><td>36
 <table><tr><td>37
 <table><tr><td>38
 <table><tr><td>39
 <table><tr><td>40
 <table><tr><td>41
 <table><tr><td>42
 <table><tr><td>43
 <table><tr><td>44
 <table><tr><td>45
 <table><tr><td>46
 <table><tr><td>47
 <table><tr><td>48
 <table><tr><td>49
 <table><tr><td>50
 <table><tr><td>51
 <table><tr><td>52
 <table><tr><td>53
 <table><tr><td>54
 <table><tr><td>55
 <table><tr><td>56
 <table><tr><td>57
 <table><tr><td>58
 <table><tr><td>59
 <table><tr><td>60
 <table><tr><td>61
 <table><tr><td>62
 <table><tr><td>63
 <table><tr><td>64
 <table><tr><td>65
 <table><tr><td>66
 <table><tr><td>67
 <table><tr><td>68
 <table><tr><td>69
 <table><tr><td>70
 <table><tr><td>71
 <table><tr><td>72
 <table><tr><td>73
 <table><tr><td>74
 <table><tr><td>75
 <table><tr><td>76
 <table><tr><td>77
 <table><tr><td>78
 <table><tr><td>79
 <table><tr><td>80
 <table><tr><td>81
 <table><tr><td>82
 <table><tr><td>83
 <table><tr><td>84
 <table><tr><td>85
 <table><tr><td>86
 <table><tr><td>87
 <table><tr><td>88
 <table><tr><td>89
 <table><tr><td>90
 <table><tr><td>91
 <table><tr><td>92
 <table><tr><td>93
 <table><tr><td>94
 <table><tr><td>95
 <table><tr><td>96
 <table><tr><td>97
 <table><tr><td>98
 <table><tr><td>99
 <table><tr><td>100
 <table><tr><td>101
 <table><tr><td>102
 <table><tr><td>103
 <table><tr><td>104
 <table><tr><td>105
 <table><tr><td>106
 <table><tr><td>107
 <table><tr><td>108
 <table><tr><td>109
 <table><tr><td>110
 <table><tr><td>111
 <table><tr><td>112
 <table><tr><td>113
 <table><tr><td>114
 <table><tr><td>115
 <table><tr><td>116
 <table><tr><td>117
 <table><tr><td>118
 <table><tr><td>119
 <table><tr><td>120
 <table><tr><td>121
 <table><tr><td>122
 <table><tr><td>123
 <table><tr><td>124
 <table><tr><td>125
 <table><tr><td>126
 <table><tr><td>127
 <table><tr><td>128
 <table><tr><td>129
 <table><tr><td>130
 <table><tr><td>131
 <table><tr><td>132
 <table><tr><td>133
 <table><tr><td>134
 <table><tr><td>135
 <table><tr><td>136
 <table><tr><td>137
 <table><tr><td>138
 <table><tr><td>139
 <table><tr><td>140
 <table><tr><td>141
 <table><tr><td>142
 <table><tr><td>143
 <table><tr><td>144
 <table><tr><td>145
 <table><tr><td>146
 <table><tr><td>147
 <table><tr><td>148
 <table><tr><td>149
 <table><tr><td>150
 <table><tr><td>151
 <table><tr><td>152
 <table><tr><td>153
 <table><tr><td>154
 <table><tr><td>155
 <table><tr><td>156
 <table><tr><td>157
 <table><tr><td>158
 <table><tr><td>159
 <table><tr><td>160
 <table><tr><td>161
 <table><tr><td>162
 <table><tr><td>163
 <table><tr><td>164
 <table><tr><td>165
 <table><tr><td>166
 <table><tr><td>167
 <table><tr><td>168
 <table><tr><td>169
 <table><tr><td>170
 <table><tr><td>171
 <table><tr><td>172
 <table><tr><td>173
 <table><tr><td>174
 <table><tr><td>175
 <table><tr><td>176
 <table><tr><td>177
 <table><tr><td>178
 <table><tr><td>179
 <table><tr><td>180
 <table><tr><td>181
 <table><tr><td>182
 <table><tr><td>183
 <table><tr><td>184
 <table><tr><td>185
 <table><tr><td>186
 <table><tr><td>187
 <table><tr><td>188
 <table><tr><td>189
 <table><tr><td>190
 <table><tr><td>191
 <table><tr><td>192
 <table><tr><td>193
 <table><tr><td>194
 <table><tr><td>195
 <table><tr><td>196
 <table><tr><td>197
 <table><tr><td>198
 <table><tr><td>199
 <table><tr><td>200
 <table><tr><td>201
 <table><tr><td>202
 <table><tr><td>203
 <table><tr><td>204
 <table><tr><td>205
 <table><tr><td>206
 <table><tr><td>207
 <table><tr><td>208
 <table><tr><td>209
 <table><tr><td>210
 <table><tr><td>211
 <table><tr><td>212
 <table><tr><td>213
 <table><tr><td>214
 <table><tr><td>215
 <table><tr><td>216
 <table><tr><td>217
 <table><tr><td>218
 <table><tr><td>219
 <table><tr><td>220
 <table><tr><td>221
 <table><tr><td>222
 <table><tr><td>223
 <table><tr><td>224
 <table><tr><td>225
 <table><tr><td>226
 <table><tr><td>227
 <table><tr><td>228
 <table><tr><td>229
 <table><tr><td>230
 <table><tr><td>231
 <table><tr><td>232
 <table><tr><td>233
 <table><tr><td>234
 <table><tr><td>235
 <table><tr><td>236
 <table><tr><td>237
 <table><tr><td>238
 <table><tr><td>239
 <table><tr><td>240
 <table><tr><td>241
 <table><tr><td>242
 <table><tr><td>243
 <table><tr><td>244
 <table><tr><td>245
 <table><tr><td>246
 <table><tr><td>247
 <table><tr><td>248
 <table><tr><td>249
 <table><tr><td>250
 <table><tr><td>251
 <table><tr><td>252
 <table><tr><td>253
 <table><tr><td>254
 <table><tr><td>255
 <table><tr><td>256
 <table><tr><td>257
 <table><tr><td>258
 <table><tr><td>259
 <table><tr><td>260
 <table><tr><td>261
 <table><tr><td>262
 <table><tr><td>263
 <table><tr><td>264
 <table><tr><td>265
 <table><tr><td>266
 <table><tr><td>267
 <table><tr><td>268
 <table><tr><td>269
 <table><tr><td>270
 <table><tr><td>271
 <table><tr><td>272
 <table><tr><td>273
 <table><tr><td>274
 <table><tr><td>275
 <table><tr><td>276
 <table><tr><td>277
 <table><tr><td>278
 <table><tr><td>279
 <table><tr><td>280
 <table><tr><td>281
 <table><tr><td>282
 <table><tr><td>283
 <table><tr><td>284
 <table><tr><td>285
 <table><tr><td>286
 <table><tr><td>287
 <table><tr><td>288
 <table><tr><td>289
 <table><tr><td>290
 <table><tr><td>291
 <table><tr><td>292
 <table><tr><td>293
 <table><tr><td>294
 <table><tr><td>295
 <table><tr><td>296
 <table><tr><td>297
 <table><tr><td>298
 <table><tr><td>299
 <table><tr><td>300
 <table><tr><td>301
 <table><tr><td>302
 <table><tr><td>303
 <table><tr><td>304
 <table><tr><td>305
 <table><tr><td>306
 <table><tr><td>307
 <table><tr><td>308
 <table><tr><td>309
 <table><tr><td>310
 <table><tr><td>311
 <table><tr><td>312
 <table><tr><td>313
 <table><tr><td>314
 <table><tr><td>315
 <table><tr><td>316
 <table><tr><td>317
 <table><tr><td>318
 <table><tr><td>319
 <table><tr><td>320
 <table><tr><td>321
 <table><tr><td>322
 <table><tr><td>323
 <table><tr><td>324
 <table><tr><td>325
 <table><tr><td>326
 <table><tr><td>327
 <table><tr><td>328
 <table><tr><td>329
 <table><tr><td>330
 <table><tr><td>331
 <table><tr><td>332
 <table><tr><td>333
 <table><tr><td>334
 <table><tr><td>335
 <table><tr><td>336
 <table><tr><td>337
 <table><tr><td>338
 <table><tr><td>339
 <table><tr><td>340
 <table><tr><td>341
 <table><tr><td>342
 <table><tr><td>343
 <table><tr><td>344
 <table><tr><td>345
 <table><tr><td>346
 <table><tr><td>347
 <table><tr><td>348
 <table><tr><td>349
 <table><tr><td>350
 <table><tr><td>351
 <table><tr><td>352
 <table><tr><td>353
 <table><tr><td>354
 <table><tr><td>355
 <table><tr><td>356
 <table><tr><td>357
 <table><tr><td>358
 <table><tr><td>359
 <table><tr><td>360
 <table><tr><td>361
 <table><tr><td>362
 <table><tr><td>363
 <table><tr><td>364
 <table><tr><td>365
 <table><tr><td>366
 <table><tr><td>367
 <table><tr><td>368
 <table><tr><td>369
 <table><tr><td>370
 <table><tr><td>371
 <table><tr><td>372
 <table><tr><td>373
 <table><tr><td>374
 <table><tr><td>375
 <table><tr><td>376
 <table><tr><td>377
 <table><tr><td>378
 <table><tr><td>379
 <table><tr><td>380
 <table><tr><td>381
 <table><tr><td>382
 <table><tr><td>383
 <table><tr><td>384
 <table><tr><td>385
 <table><tr><td>386
 <table><tr><td>387
 <table><tr><td>388
 <table><tr><td>389
 <table><tr><td>390
 <table><tr><td>391
 <table><tr><td>392
 <table><tr><td>393
 <table><tr><td>394
 <table><tr><td>395
 <table><tr><td>396
 <table><tr><td>397
 <table><tr><td>398
 <table><tr><td>399
 <table><tr><td>400
 <table><tr><td>401
 <table><tr><td>402
 <table><tr><td>403
 <table><tr><td>404
 <table><tr><td>405
 <table><tr><td>406
 <table><tr><td>407
 <table><tr><td>408
 <table><tr><td>409
 <table><tr><td>410
 <table><tr><td>411
 <table><tr><td>412
 <table><tr><td>413
 <table><tr><td>414
 <table><tr><td>415
 <table><tr><td>416
 <table><tr><td>417
 <table><tr><td>418
 <table><tr><td>419
 <table><tr><td>420
 <table><tr><td>421
 <table><tr><td>422
 <table><tr><td>423
 <table><tr><td>424
 <table><tr><td>425
 <table><tr><td>426
 <table><tr><td>427
 <table><tr><td>428
 <table><tr><td>429
 <table><tr><td>430
 <table><tr><td>431
 <table><tr><td>432
 <table><tr><td>433
 <table><tr><td>434
 <table><tr><td>435
 <table><tr><td>436
 <table><tr><td>437
 <table><tr><td>438
 <table><tr><td>439
 <table><tr><td>440
 <table><tr><td>441
 <table><tr><td>442
 <table><tr><td>443
 <table><tr><td>444
 <table><tr><td>445
 <table><tr><td>446
 <table><tr><td>447
 <table><tr><td>448
 <table><tr><td>449
 <table><tr><td>450
 <table><tr><td>451
 <table><tr><td>452
 <table><tr><td>453
 <table><tr><td>454
 <table><tr><td>455
 <table><tr><td>456
 <table><tr><td>457
 <table><tr><td>458
 <table><tr><td>459
 <table><tr><td>460
 <table><tr><td>461
 <table><tr><td>462
 <table><tr><td>463
 <table><tr><td>464
 <table><tr><td>465
 <table><tr><td>466
 <table><tr><td>467
 <table><tr><td>468
 <table><tr><td>469
 <table><tr><td>470
 <table><tr><td>471
 <table><tr><td>472
 <table><tr><td>473
 <table><tr><td>474
 <table><tr><td>475
 <table><tr><td>476
 <table><tr><td>477
 <table><tr><td>478
 <table><tr><td>479
 <table><tr><td>480
 <table><tr><td>481
 <table><tr><td>482
 <table><tr><td>483
 <table><tr><td>484
 <table><tr><td>485
 <table><tr><td>486
 <table><tr><td>487
 <table><tr><td>488
 <table><tr><td>489
 <table><tr><td>490
 <table><tr><td>491
 <table><tr><td>492
 <table><tr><td>493
 <table><tr><td>494
 <table><tr><td>495
 <table><tr><td>496
 <table><tr><td>497
 <table><tr><td>498
 <table><tr><td>499
 <table><tr><td>500
 <table><tr><td>501
 <table><tr><td>502
 <table><tr><td>503
 <table><tr><td>504
 <table><tr><td>505
 <table><tr><td>506
 <table><tr><td>507
 <table><tr><td>508
 <table><tr><td>509
 <table><tr><td>510
 <table><tr><td>511
 <table><tr><td>512
 <table><tr><td>513
 <table><tr><td>514
 <table><tr><td>515
 <table><tr><td>516
 <table><tr><td>517
 <table><tr><td>518
 <table><tr><td>519
 <table><tr><td>520
 <table><tr><td>521
 <table><tr><td>522
 <table><tr><td>523
 <table><tr><td>524
 <table><tr><td>525
 <table><tr><td>526
 <table><tr><td>527
 <table><tr><td>528
 <table><tr><td>529
 <table><tr><td>530
 <table><tr><td>531
 <table><tr><td>532
 <table><tr><td>533
 <table><tr><td>534
 <table><tr><td>535
 <table><tr><td>536
 <table><tr><td>537
 <table><tr><td>538
 <table><tr><td>539
 <table><tr><td>540
 <table><tr><td>541
 <table><tr><td>542
 <table><tr><td>543
 <table><tr><td>544
 <table><tr><td>545
 <table><tr><td>546
 <table><tr><td>547
 <table><tr><td>548
 <table><tr><td>549
 <table><tr><td>550
 <table><tr><td>551
 <table><tr><td>552
 <table><tr><td>553
 <table><tr><td>554
 <table><tr><td>555
 <table><tr><td>556
 <table><tr><td>557
 <table><tr><td>558
 <table><tr><td>559
 <table><tr><td>560
 <table><tr><td>561
 <table><tr><td>562
 <table><tr><td>563
 <table><tr><td>564
 <table><tr><td>565
 <table><tr><td>566
 <table><tr><td>567
 <table><tr><td>568
 <table><tr><td>569
 <table><tr><td>570
 <table><tr><td>571
 <table><tr><td>572
 <table><tr><td>573
 <table><tr><td>574
 <table><tr><td>575
 <table><tr><td>576
 <table><tr><td>577
 <table><tr><td>578
 <table><tr><td>579
 <table><tr><td>580
 <table><tr><td>581
 <table><tr><td>582
 <table><tr><td>583
 <table><tr><td>584
 <table><tr><td>585
 <table><tr><td>586
 <table><tr><td>587
 <table><tr><td>588
 <table><tr><td>589
 <table><tr><td>590
 <table><tr><td>591
 <table><tr><td>592
 <table><tr><td>593
 <table><tr><td>594
 <table><tr><td>595
 <table><tr><td>596
 <table><tr><td>597
 <table><tr><td>598
 <table><tr><td>599
 <table><tr><td>600
 <table><tr><td>601
 <table><tr><td>602
 <table><tr><td>603
 <table><tr><td>604
 <table><tr><td>605
 <table><tr><td>606
 <table><tr><td>607
 <table><tr><td>608
 <table><tr><td>609
 <table><tr><td>610
 <table><tr><td>611
 <table><tr><td>612
 <table><tr><td>613
 <table><tr><td>614
 <table><tr><td>615
 <table><tr><td>616
 <table><tr><td>617
 <table><tr><td>618
 <table><tr><td>619
 <table><tr><td>620
 <table><tr><td>621
 <table><tr><td>622
 <table><tr><td>623
 <table><tr><td>624
 <table><tr><td>625
 <table><tr><td>626
 <table><tr><td>627
 <table><tr><td>628
 <table><tr><td>629
 <table><tr><td>630
 <table><tr><td>631
 <table><tr><td>632
 <table><tr><td>633
 <table><tr><td>634
 <table><tr><td>635
 <table><tr><td>636
 <table><tr><td>637
 <table><tr><td>638
 <table><tr><td>639
 <table><tr><td>640
 <table><tr><td>641
 <table><tr><td>642
 <table><tr><td>643
 <table><tr><td>644
 <table><tr><td>645
 <table><tr><td>646
 <table><tr><td>647
 <table><tr><td>648
 <table><tr><td>649
 <table><tr><td>650
 <table><tr><td>651
 <table><tr><td>652
 <table><tr><td>653
 <table><tr><td>654
 <table><tr><td>655
 <table><tr><td>656
 <table><tr><td>657
 <table><tr><td>658
 <table><tr><td>659
 <table><tr><td>660
 <table><tr><td>661
 <table><tr><td>662
 <table><tr><td>663
 <table><tr><td>664
 <table><tr><td>665
 <table><tr><td>666
 <table><tr><td>667
 <table><tr><td>668
 <table><tr><td>669
 <table><tr><td>670
 <table><tr><td>671
 <table><tr><td>672
 <table><tr><td>673
 <table><tr><td>674
 <table><tr><td>675
 <table><tr><td>676
 <table><tr><td>677
 <table><tr><td>678
 <table><tr><td>679
 <table><tr><td>680
 <table><tr><td>681
 <table><tr><td>682
 <table><tr><td>683
 <table><tr><td>684
 <table><tr><td>685
 <table><tr><td>686
 <table><tr><td>687
 <table><tr><td>688
 <table><tr><td>689
 <table><tr><td>690
 <table><tr><td>691
 <table><tr><td>692
 <table><tr><td>693
 <table><tr><td>694
 <table><tr><td>695
 <table><tr><td>696
 <table><tr><td>697
 <table><tr><td>698
 <table><tr><td>699
 <table><tr><td>700
 <table><tr><td>701
 <table><tr><td>702
 <table><tr><td>703
 <table><tr><td>704
 <table><tr><td>705
 <table><tr><td>706
 <table><tr><td>707
 <table><tr><td>708
 <table><tr><td>709
 <table><tr><td>710
 <table><tr><td>711
 <table><tr><td>712
 <table><tr><td>713
 <table><tr><td>714
 <table><tr><td>715
 <table><tr><td>716
 <table><tr><td>717
 <table><tr><td>718
 <table><tr><td>719
 <table><tr><td>720
 <table><tr><td>721
 <table><tr><td>722
 <table><tr><td>723
 <table><tr><td>724
 <table><tr><td>725
 <table><tr><td>726
 <table><tr><td>727
 <table><tr><td>728
 <table><tr><td>729
 <table><tr><td>730
 <table><tr><td>731
 <table><tr><td>732
 <table><tr><td>733
 <table><tr><td>734
 <table><tr><td>735
 <table><tr><td>736
 <table><tr><td>737
 <table><tr><td>738
 <table><tr><td>739
 <table><tr><td>740
 <table><tr><td>741
 <table><tr><td>742
 <table><tr><td>743
 <table><tr><td>744
 <table><tr><td>745
 <table><tr><td>746
 <table><tr><td>747
 <table><tr><td>748
 <table><tr><td>749
 <table><tr><td>750
 <table><tr><td>751
 <table><tr><td>752
 <table><tr><td>753
 <table><tr><td>754
 <table><tr><td>755
 <table><tr><td>756
 <table><tr><td>757
 <table><tr><td>758
 <table><tr><td>759
 <table><tr><td>760
 <table><tr><td>761
 <table><tr><td>762
 <table><tr><td>763
 <table><tr><td>764
 <table><tr><td>765
 <table><tr><td>766
 <table><tr><td>767
 <table><tr><td>768
 <table><tr><td>769
 <table><tr><td>770
 <table><tr><td>771
 <table><tr><td>772
 <table><tr><td>773
 <table><tr><td>774
 <table><tr><td>775
 <table><tr><td>776
 <table><tr><td>777
 <table><tr><td>778
 <table><tr><td>779
 <table><tr><td>780
 <table><tr><td>781
 <table><tr><td>782
 <table><tr><td>783
 <table><tr><td>784
 <table><tr><td>785
 <table><tr><td>786
 <table><tr><td>787
 <table><tr><td>788
 <table><tr><td>789
 <table><tr><td>790
 <table><tr><td>791
 <table><tr><td>792
 <table><tr><td>793
 <table><tr><td>794
 <table><tr><td>795
 <table><tr><td>796
 <table><tr><td>797
 <table><tr><td>798
 <table><tr><td>799
 <table><tr><td>800
 <table><tr><td>801
 <table><tr><td>802
 <table><tr><td>803
 <table><tr><td>804
 <table><tr><td>805
 <table><tr><td>806
 <table><tr><td>807
 <table><tr><td>808
 <table><tr><td>809
 <table><tr><td>810
 <table><tr><td>811
 <table><tr><td>812
 <table><tr><td>813
 <table><tr><td>814
 <table><tr><td>815
 <table><tr><td>816
 <table><tr><td>817
 <table><tr><td>818
 <table><tr><td>819
 <table><tr><td>820
 <table><tr><td>821
 <table><tr><td>822
 <table><tr><td>823
 <table><tr><td>824
 <table><tr><td>825
 <table><tr><td>826
 <table><tr><td>827
 <table><tr><td>828
 <table><tr><td>829
 <table><tr><td>830
 <table><tr><td>831
 <table><tr><td>832
 <table><tr><td>833
 <table><tr><td>834
 <table><tr><td>835
 <table><tr><td>836
 <table><tr><td>837
 <table><tr><td>838
 <table><tr><td>839
 <table><tr><td>840
 <table><tr><td>841
 <table><tr><td>842
 <table><tr><td>843
 <table><tr><td>844
 <table><tr><td>845
 <table><tr><td>846
 <table><tr><td>847
 <table><tr><td>848
 <table><tr><td>849
 <table><tr><td>850
 <table><tr><td>851
 <table><tr><td>852
 <table><tr><td>853
 <table><tr><td>854
 <table><tr><td>855
 <table><tr><td>856
 <table><tr><td>857
 <table><tr><td>858
 <table><tr><td>859
 <table><tr><td>860
 <table><tr><td>861
 <table><tr><td>862
 <table><tr><td>863
 <table><tr><td>864
 <table><tr><td>865
 <table><tr><td>866
 <table><tr><td>867
 <table><tr><td>868
 <table><tr><td>869
 <table><tr><td>870
 <table><tr><td>871
 <table><tr><td>872
 <table><tr><td>873
 <table><tr><td>874
 <table><tr><td>875
 <table><tr><td>876
 <table><tr><td>877
 <table><tr><td>878
 <table><tr><td>879
 <table><tr><td>880
 <table><tr><td>881
 <table><tr><td>882
 <table><tr><td>883
 <table><tr><td>884
 <table><tr><td>885
 <table><tr><td>886
 <table><tr><td>887
 <table><tr><td>888
 <table><tr><td>889
 <table><tr><td>890
 <table><tr><td>891
 <table><tr><td>892
 <table><tr><td>893
 <table><tr><td>894
 <table><tr><td>895
 <table><tr><td>896
 <table><tr><td>897
 <table><tr><td>898
 <table><tr><td>899
 <table><tr><td>900
 <table><tr><td>901
 <table><tr><td>902
 <table><tr><td>903
 <table><tr><td>904
 <table><tr><td>905
 <table><tr><td>906
 <table><tr><td>907
 <table><tr><td>908
 <table><tr><td>909
 <table><tr><td>910
 <table><tr><td>911
 <table><tr><td>912
 <table><tr><td>913
 <table><tr><td>914
 <table><tr><td>915
 <table><tr><td>916
 <table><tr><td>917
 <table><tr><td>918
 <table><tr><td>919
 <table><tr><td>920
 <table><tr><td>921
 <table><tr><td>922
 <table><tr><td>923
 <table><tr><td>924
 <table><tr><td>925
 <table><tr><td>926
 <table><tr><td>927
 <table><tr><td>928
 <table><tr><td>929
 <table><tr><td>930
 <table><tr><td>931
 <table><tr><td>932
 <table><tr><td>933
 <table><tr><td>934
 <table><tr><td>935
 <table><tr><td>936
 <table><tr><td>937
 <table><tr><td>938
 <table><tr><td>939
 <table><tr><td>940
 <table><tr><td>941
 <table><tr><td>942
 <table><tr><td>943
 <table><tr><td>944
 <table><tr><td>945
 <table><tr><td>946
 <table><tr><td>947
 <table><tr><td>948
 <table><tr><td>949
 <table><tr><td>950
 <table><tr><td>951
 <table><tr><td>952
 <table><tr><td>953
 <table><tr><td>954
 <table><tr><td>955
 <table><tr><td>956
 <table><tr><td>957
 <table><tr><td>958
 <table><tr><td>959
 <table><tr><td>960
 <table><tr><td>961
 <table><tr><td>962
 <table><tr><td>963
 <table><tr><td>964
 <table><tr><td>965
 <table><tr><td>966
 <table><tr><td>967
 <table><tr><td>968
 <table><tr><td>969
 <table><tr><td>970
 <table><tr><td>971
 <table><tr><td>972
 <table><tr><td>973
 <table><tr><td>974
 <table><tr><td>975
 <table><tr><td>976
 <table><tr><td>977
 <table><tr><td>978
 <table><tr><td>979
 <table><tr><td>980
 <table><tr><td>981
 <table><tr><td>982
 <table><tr><td>983
 <table><tr><td>984
 <table><tr><td>985
 <table><tr><td>986
 <table><tr><td>987
 <table><tr><td>988
 <table><tr><td>989
 <table><tr><td>990
 <table><tr><td>991
 <table><tr><td>992
 <table><tr><td>993
 <table><tr><td>994
 <table><tr><td>995
 <table><tr><td>996
 <table><tr><td>997
 <table><tr><td>998
 <table><tr><td>999
 <table><tr><td>1000
```

Comment: How much RAM did you have when running these tests. I read somewhere (on my phone and I can't remember for the life of me where it was) that some browsers are happy to keep trying until you run out of memory.

Comment: @NickMcMahon only 4gb on the tested machine. I will test on my main workstation which has 12gb and post my result. For chrome the real limitation will probably still be 127 as the table markup is butchered and seems to be a bug not caused by a lack of memory as it renders incorrectly without crashing the tab for a further 150+ tables. IE11 does seem to have a chance to chew through extra RAM and display more tables, though.

Comment: @NickMcMahon - interestingly, I was able to get IE 11 to handle up to around 350 nested tables without crashing on my workstation with 12gb RAM. IE 11 could actually handle more tables than Edge which crashed with 350!

Comment: Giving all the ups I can to you. The memory management for tables seems pretty interesting between browsers. Thanks for the testing!